# Manga about a struggling writer who gets a mysterious game on his phone and fights red ants from the game that start appearing in the real world

Tags: story-identification, manga

A struggling writer ends up getting a mysterious game on his phone called: The God Maker. In the game, there are ants that, if he taps, they get killed and then he gains a god coin for each one killed. However, after gaining a coin, he decides to do a hunter evaluation test, but he ends up being a G rank (the lowest). Depressed, he goes home and then tries to finish the chapter to his manga, before the due date, which happened to be the next day.

Later (don't remember what happens after), his niece shows up and he is taking care of her until his sister comes to pick her daughter back up. In the meantime though, he gets her chocolate ice cream, only for a monster to appear in front of them. A hunter who is weaker against the monster tries to distract it while they escape. The main character however, uses an ability he got (which makes his pointer finger like a remote) at the hunter, hoping that he can help her. When he uses his ability at the hunter, it causes her to become powerful enough to easily kill the monster.

Later, he tries to throw his phone into the body of water in front of him, but can't do it.

Later, he continues playing the game, aggressively tapping, and with some difficulty manages to kill the red ant in front of him (on the screen).

Later, he ends up having to deal with an army of red ants inside his bedroom. He finds a lighter and some bug spray and ends up blow torching the ants, not only killing them all, but also setting his bedroom on fire (I can't remember if he lives in a house or an apartment).

Later, he gets kidnapped and taken to a secluded place where, before the thugs can do anything to the main character, they are killed by a really fast and sharp blur. The main character is the only one left and the worst part is that he is still tied to the chair. He sees the second red ant army and finally gets to see the deadly soldier that killed the thugs with razor sharp arms.

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Answer (score 1):

Is it I’ll be Taking a Break for Personal Reasons / 일신상의 이유로 잠시 휴재합 니다 ?

[Reddit summary](https://www.reddit.com/r/manhwa/comments/yswfcq/who_approved_this_manwha_title/):

> Mc is manga artist and got a app download, which essentially made him a god of that app and is fighting off insects that are trying to kill from the “app” world